# Simply connected open set forms a basis for $\mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: general-topology

I am a beginner in Algebraic topology. While trying to solve exercises I got stuck in the following problem:

Problem: Set of all simply connected open subsets of $\mathbb{R^2}$ forms a basis for a topology in $\mathbb{R^2}$

My attempt:

I proceed by definition of the basis of a topological space. I managed to show the first axiom for basis, that is for any $x_0\in \mathbb{R^2}$ there exist a simply connected open set $U$(namely, open disc around $z_0$) in $\mathbb{R^2}$ containing $z_0$.

However, I got stuck in proving the second axiom that says if $z_0\in U_1 \cap U_1$ (where $U_1$ and $U_2$ are basis elements) then there is a basis element $U_3$ containing $z_0$ such that $U_3 \subset U_1 \cap U_2$.

Thanks a lot for any sort of help!!

Comment: Any open disk is  a simply conneceted open set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that all open disks in $\mathbb{R}$ are open and simply connected. Simply take a small enough $\varepsilon$ such that $B(z_0,\varepsilon)\subseteq U_1\cap U_2$. You can do this since the intersection is again an open set.

Comment: thanks a lot for your kind answer!! Further, I want to know how the situation changes If I take my space to be $\mathbb{R^2} minus \{(0,0)\}$ instead of $\mathbb{R^2}$