# Simply connected open set need not form a basis for a topological space

Tags: general-topology

I am a beginner in Algebraic topology. From my previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4236414/simply-connected-open-set-forms-a-basis-for-mathbbr2) I know that the collection of all simply connected open subsets in $\mathbb{R^2}$ forms a basis of $\mathbb R^2$ with the usual topology.

I want to find (if exists) a topological space in which collections of all simply connected open sets do not form a basis.

Comment: $X = \mathbb R^2 \setminus \mathbb Q^2$ is one example: indeed all nonempty open set are not simply connected.

Comment: @ArcticChar, thanks a lot for your kind help. Can you give me some idea how the simply connected open sets in this space look like

Comment: there is no simply connected open set in this topology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One such example is $\mathbb{Q}$ since every open subset in $\mathbb{Q}$ is disconnected (and thus not simply connected).

Another interesting example is [the Hawaiian earring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_earring). Every neighbourhood around the origin is not simply connected even when connected. The idea is that every neighbourhood around the origin contains some circle, and paths around that circle cannot leave it.